# Editable ListView Items

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I want to Edit my `ListView` items. for example; I have a `listView` item i clicked this item and I add `string value` with `edit text` afterwards I again click this item and I add new `string value` alongside to previous `string value`, and again, again, again. When I click this item I want edit this listitem. How I do that?

Java sourcecode:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tvDers;
    EditText etDers, etDersSaati;
    EditText etNot;
    LinearLayout LayoutDers;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnDersEkle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDersEkle);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        etDers = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        //Dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        build.setTitle("Ders Ekle");
        build.setView(etDers);

        build.setPositiveButton("Tamam", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                adapter.add(etDers.getText().toString());   
            }
        });
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        final AlertDialog alertDers = build.create();

        btnDersEkle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDers.show();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post the code you already have

Comment: We need code in order to more easily understand what is happening. It sounds like you would be looking at a creating a custom view, which would have an ArrayList<String> value. You can keep adding/removing to this ArrayList<String> based on some specific function, and handle programmatically adding a TextView for each item within the array.

Comment: @ItzHoudini  @ Tomer Shemesh  edited. I want edit my listview items. like that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2dNih90u1E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save item values in ordering Collection. Set this collection in adapter. Add and remove this values and after call `notifyDataSetChanged` for adapter.

Try like this.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
         String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(int position);
         item += "YourText";
         ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter ) parent.getAdapter();
         adapter.insert(item, position);
    }
```

Sorry, but now I can't test this code. So I can not say for sure that it is correct. Try different variants and you'll get.

**UPDATE**
From dialog clickListener you can try this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
      ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter ) listView.getAdapter();
      String item = (String) listView.getSelectedItem();
      item += "YourText";

     adapter.insert(item, position);
}
```

Comment: i dont remove values. ı want do like that. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2dNih90u1E

Comment: okay. Change your items and add new. What's the problem? You can get item for position of collection and change it.

Comment: Do not use copy/paste. Try to understand the logic.

Comment: I am glad to hear it)

Comment: :) can ı ask one question?
How I use it with Positive Button? I click on Positive Button and I will change with my text. How I do it?

Comment: where is positive button? In dialog?

Comment: Thanks a lot but position variable where is it? How i get this var?

Comment: int position = listView.getSelectedItemPosition();

Comment: I try it but i have that log when i click positive button; The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.